# Tensorflow: Fill the tensor with dynamically computed value tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

The two tensor values are computed and I tried to create the tensor of dynamic shape. E is a slice of a tensor variable, labelLen_l is a placeholder, tensorval1 and tensorval2 are tensors of dimension 1.

`num1 = tf.reduce_sum(tf.eye(labelLen_l, dtype=tf.float64)*E, 1)
 num2 = tf.fill(num1.shape, tensor_val1)
 num3 = tf.fill(num1.shape, tensor_val2)`

It says `ValueError: Tried to convert 'dims' to a tensor and failed. Error: Cannot convert a partially known TensorShape to a Tensor: <unknown>`

I am trying to compute num1 + num2 + num3 and hence their dimension should match. Any suggestions to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use tf.shape in order to get the tensor shape as a tensor type.

> num2 = tf.fill(num1.shape, tensor_val1)
>
> num3 = tf.fill(num1.shape, tensor_val2)

should be:

```
num2 = tf.fill(tf.shape(num1), tensor_val1)
num3 = tf.fill(tf.shape(num1), tensor_val2)
```

Comment: It  seems that I can only have  number values for tensor_val* , do you know how would it be possible to have lets say a tuple instead of just one value. I am trying to get something like , tf.fill(tf.shape(num1), (tensor_val1,tesor_val2))